# How to get total result set size on a group_by count query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, kaminari

I have the following query within my model:

```
Post.where("created_utc > ? AND lower(category) = ?", 0, 'videos').group(:domain).order('count_all desc').page(1).per(25).count
```

I'm using the `kaminari` gem for pagination but the problem is this: this query returns what appears to be a sorted hash. However I have no way of knowing what the total result count is.

If you prefer not to take `kaminari` into consideration, you can reference the following query:

```
Post.where("created_utc > ? AND lower(category) = ?", min_time, subreddit.downcase).group(:domain).order('count_all desc').limit(limit).offset(start).count
```

Regardless, I have no way of figuring out what the total number of results is. How can I go about resolving this? Is there some way to figure out what the total result set size would be without the limit?

Comment: Have you tried `size` instead of count?

Comment: @BroiSatse no but even if I do, how does that solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `.length` instead of `.count`, like this:

```
Post.where("created_utc > ? AND lower(category) = ?", 0, 'videos').group(:domain).order('count_all desc').page(1).per(25).length
```

> - `.count` performs a SQL COUNT
> - `.length` calculates the length of the resultant array
>
> courtesy of @BenHawker at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34541020/380607

Answer (score 0):

Aside from ruby based methods, I would also benchmark running a separate database-based count.

```
posts        = Post.where("created_utc > ? AND lower(category) = ?", min_time, subreddit.downcase)
domain_count = posts.count("distinct domain")
result       = posts.group(:domain).order('count_all desc').limit(limit).offset(start).count
```

Answer (score 0):

Kaminari provides a `total_count` method. https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/blob/master/README.md#the-per-scope

Answer (score -1):

I would split it to multiple lines:

```
# 1. get the results
posts = Post.where("created_utc > ? AND lower(category) = ?", 0, 'videos').group(:domain).order('count_all desc')
# 2. count the total size
total_size = posts.count
# 3. use kaminari for pagination
posts_paged = posts.page(1).per(25)
```

Comment: But doesn't this wind up running multiple queries? I was hoping to accomplish this in a single query.

Comment: What you need are two separate things: total count and paged result array, right? I think you need at least two queries to achieve it.

Comment: There is a way to avoid two queries but it may be much more costly. A better idea here might be to cache the query (with something like memcache) so that it doesn't need to be expensive every time.

Comment: Also, that way you also limit the result set on the first request.