# How to find size of query result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, sqlite, group-by

I have the following query in rails:

```
records = Record.select('y_id, source')
                .where(:source => source, :y_id => y_id)
                .group(:y_id, :source)
                .having('count(*) = 1')
```

I get the following output if I `puts records`:
`[#<Record source: "XYZ", y_id: 10000009>, #<Record source: "XYZ", y_id: 10000070>]`

This looks like there are 2 elements in the output array. But when I try to do `records.size` I get:
`{[10000009, "XYZ"]=>1, [10000070, "XYZ"]=>1}`

> - Why doesn't `records.size` print `2` when records is an array having 2 elements? Is the `group by` query result behaving differently for some reason?
> - What should I do to get the size of `records`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could be on the wrong track but I think the issue is to do with the way `.size` works.

Size will automatically try to determine whether to call `.count` or `.length`. These behave in the followings ways:

- .count performs a SQL COUNT
- .length calculates the length of the resultant array

However on occassion `.size` will return a hash (as it has decided to use `.count`)

So your solution may be to use `.length` which will return an integer.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

You can get it using :

```
results.length
```

The size method uses the sql count method which behaves this way.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried a variant on the above example (using my own existing Rails app and DB) and it worked without issues:

```
records = Site.select('name','url')
    .where(:name => 'Washington Post', :url => 'https://www.washingtonpost.com/')
    .group(:name, :url)
    .having('count(*) = 1')

 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Site id: nil, name: "Washington Post", url: "https://www.washingtonpost.com/">]> 

records.size

 => 1
```

Are you sure your Record model inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure my model inherits from ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: You're probably right: at the point I made this post (yesterday), I didn't have enough reputation to comment but I wanted to provide an example of a working variant of his question.